# Regex - extracting numbers from string

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create REGEX DEFINITION in Oracle SQL, that will return some number of rows, with float number from string. How to do this?

case1 (n=4: **48**-48h, **72**-72h, **96**-96h, **120**-120h)

n=4 > 4 records per range, retrieved values will be: 48.00, 72.00, 96.00 120.00

case2 (n=5: **0**-0h, **24.21**-24.21h, **47.77**-47.75h, **71.75**-71.75h, **96.08**-96.08h)

n=5 > 5 records per range, retrieved values will be: 00.00, 24.21, 47.77, 71.75, 96.08

input:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('(n=4: 48-48h, 72-72h, 96-96h, 120-120h)', MY_REGEX_DEFINITION ) as X from dual;
```

output rows:

```
X
48.00
72.00
96.00
120.00
```

Comment: Please show your sample input and your expected output!

Comment: Please show your sample input and your expected output!

Comment: your input sql not working what exactly do you want??

Comment: I want to define MY_REGEX_DEFINITION in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked up an example on how to split a string since you first need to do that to find all numbers in the string. Here is my re-work of that example to fit your question. Unfortunately it returns a null row at the end but it should be something to start with.

```
SELECT CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(result_row, '[^=]\d+\.?\d*' ) AS NUMBER)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR('(n=5: 0-0h, 24.21-24.21h, 47.77-47.75h, 71.75-71.75h, 96.08-96.08h)', '[^ ]+h', 1, lines.column_value)) result_row
    FROM dual,
    TABLE (CAST (MULTISET
        (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual
            CONNECT BY instr('(n=5: 0-0h, 24.21-24.21h, 47.77-47.75h, 71.75-71.75h, 96.08-96.08h)', '-', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
        ) AS sys.odciNumberList ) ) lines
    ORDER BY  lines.column_value)//
```

[This is the article](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/split-comma-delimited-strings-in-a-table-in-oracle/) I took the example code from.

Comment: I found two error: from pair 22.21-24.21h query returns second number not first. For '(n=2: 0-0h, 24.09-0h)', query will return only one row with 0 value.

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question that you wanted the first number and the second one was the easiest to match due to the 'h'.

Comment: @Cugar, I have updated the patterns to match for both `REGEXP_SUBSTR` calls so that the first number is returned. Still one extra null row returned.

Comment: I marked first number as bold. Thanks, now it works :)

Comment: How to change this SQL to also operate on case '(n=3: 0-0h, 0.05-0.05h, -0.11- -0.12h)' ? Now it returns only positive numbers: 0, 0.05 and 0.11, not -0.11.

Comment: ... and how to return only rows when value x < y in all pairs of numbers ( e.g. 24.21-24.22h) in string. Thanks in advance!